# Database Matching Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I am working on a system which will match members based on exact or/and closeness of their choice of product categories.

For eg. Would suggest to a member other members whom have the same choice or likely or close selections.

Eg. Fred selects (Cereals, Fruits, Beverages, Apparel)
Mike selects (Cereals, Fruits)
Jane selects  (Fruits, Beverages, Apparel)

I want to match and suggest to Fred that a member Jane has categories in common

Any pointers?

Comment: Let me suggest this book, as it explains exactly what you are looking for: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/dp/0596529325

Comment: I added the algorithm tag because this is mostly language independent. It's an interesting topic... there are many papers on it. What type of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I think that would be worth a vote as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/dp/0596529325](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325). I have it, and it has many examples of useful algorithms that do exactly what you want. In fact, the second chapter is all about making recommendations.

Although the primary language it uses is Python, it isn't too difficult to apply the examples to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Do a query on the user's categories where category = '$category_id1' and category = '$category_id2', etc. You will also need to put the categories into sub categories so that if they belong to the same parent category they are considered similar. (i.e. Tops -> Tees, Graphic Tees, Long Sleeve Shirts, Sweaters...)

Comment: That is exactly my concern. There are so many categories and I thought it would be weird to list all of them and match them. Is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: But make sure you cache this information. If you run this on every page load, it is going to start to get very slow. You can store this information in a table and recompute/update it regularly using triggers or a cron job so that you always have a quick best guess available.